# How to add a line break in Highchart legend in R?

Tags: r, highcharts

I made an org chart and I need to manually determine the line breaks of text.

I'm using paste() to join a text with the value of an object. But the break isn't working.

Follow the example:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

value <-  1
  
  highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
    hc_add_series(
      data = list(
        list(from = 'A1', to = 'A2'),
        list(from = 'A2', to = 'A3')),
      nodes = list(
        list(id = 'A1', name = paste("I need to break the text", value,  sep="\n"))), #TEXT
      nodeWidth = 150) # increasing the width of the box, to illustrate
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `\n` use the html tag `<br>` as separator:

```r
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
library(tidyverse)

value <-  1

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'A1', to = 'A2'),
      list(from = 'A2', to = 'A3')),
    nodes = list(
      list(id = 'A1', name = paste("I need to break the text", value,  sep="<br>"))), #TEXT
    nodeWidth = 150) # increasing the width of the box, to illustrate
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please know how to change the font size of the text? I made a few attempts, without success. @stefan

Comment: I hate these interactive libraries. (; Try with adding `hc_add_series(..., dataLabels = list(style = list(fontSize = '40px'))`.